# Move content with menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, text, menu

I have made myself a slideout menu which I plan to use but what I have hit some trouble with is that I can't get the content of the page to move to the left when the menu is exposed. The menu overlaps the content on the page making it unreadable, I know this is probably a JavaScript issue but I have tried looking for the solution and have come up short.

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

var slideWidth = $('#pageslide').outerWidth();

$('.slideIt, #pageslide a.close').on("click", function(){
    $('.slideIt').toggleClass('active');

```
if($('#pageslide').is(':visible')) { 
  $('#pageslide').animate({
    right: '-'+slideWidth
  }, 400, function(){
    $('#pageslide').hide();
  } );
  $('.wrapper').animate({
    marginRight: '0'
  }, 400 );
} 
else{
  $('#pageslide').show().animate({
    right: '0'
  }, 400 );
  $('.wrapper').animate({
    marginRight: slideWidth
  }, 400 );
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ujyj24op/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Follow the code might helps you.**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var slideWidth = $('#pageslide').outerWidth(); //grab width of the sliding menu so that this can be controlled in the css only

  $('.slideIt, #pageslide a.close').on("click", function(){  //click function
    $('.slideIt').toggleClass('active'); //toggle the active close vs open icon
    
    if($('#pageslide').is(':visible')) {  //if visible then hide it 
      $('#pageslide').animate({
        right: '-'+slideWidth
      }, 400, function(){
        $('#pageslide').hide();
      } );
      $('.wrapper, #text').animate({
        marginRight: '0'
      }, 400 );
    } 
    else{                                //else show it
      $('#pageslide').show().animate({
        right: '0'
      }, 400 );
      $('.wrapper, #text').animate({
        marginRight: slideWidth
      }, 400 );
    }
     
  });

});
```

```css
body{
  background-color:rgb(204,204,204);
}
a{
  display:block;
}
#text{
  position:absolute;
  width:150px;
  top:200px;
  right:100px;
}
.slideItWrapper{
  position:relative;
}
.wrapper{
  position:absolute;
  top:110px;
  right:100px;
}
.menu-item{
  @include transition-property(all);
  @include transition-duration(0.2s);

  display:block;
  width:25px;
  height:1px;
  margin:0 0 7px;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

#pageslide {
  display:none;
  position:absolute;
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  overflow:scroll;
  height:100%;
  z-index: 999999;
  width:340px;
 
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
  right:-340px;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <a href="#" class="slideIt">
     <span class="menu-item"></span>
    <span class="menu-item"></span>
    <span class="menu-item"></span>
    </a>
</div>
<aside id="pageslide">
<div id="modal">
  <h3>Menu!</h3>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
</aside>
</div>
<div id="text"><p>hello this is my placeholder text lets see if you move please move beause I will be annoyed if you don't</p></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the #text section also to your slide funtion to show. It will then slide that content over as much as the side content.
Example:

```
 else{                                //else show it
  $('#pageslide, #text').show().animate({
    right: '0'
  }, 400 );
  $('.wrapper, #text').animate({
    marginRight: slideWidth
  }, 400 );
}
```

This can then be modified a little better, but will give you an idea on how to do it. (One way) with already code you have.